# Export angular grid data to excel

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular grid to display the data , Is there any way to export to excel :
 http://www.angulargrid.com/

Not tried any code as I am new to angular. My question is - is it possible to do that ? As angular grid is not using table to display the data.It uses div instead

Answer (score 1):

It is supported.  See the documentation:
http://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-export/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know directly how to export from angulargrid method.

But there is a general plugin for angular to do that, it converts data,arrays etc to Exportable CSV that you can find here :-

[Ng-CSV](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv)

Example [Here](https://asafdav.github.io/ng-csv/example/)

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

As angular-grid having issue with their grid so you can refer his example for more details you can see following link
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3800
from csv you can convert to excel than help 
If you are using kendo ui then there is facility of exporting it to excel

Hope this will help you out.